# Warhammer 40k Dark Eldar+Harlequins

Tags: warhammer-40k

Can I have a Haemunclous start a match with a unit of Harlequin Troupe in the deep strike reserves using the webway portal rule?  With both having their own codex's now they're battle brothers, I know I can't start the Troupe in a Raider so I was hoping this would be a decent loophole.